# add options to drop down list with javascript

Tags: javascript, list, drop-down-menu

I need to add options to a drop down list. I have an array with the options that I need in the drop down list, but I'm not sure how to append the array to the list

```
var productList = document.getElementById("selectFood");
var foodOption = document.createElement("option");

foodOption.textContent = [{ 
    option1: "Meat Lovers"
}, {
    option2: "Buffalo Wings"
}, {
    option3: "margherita"
}, {
    option4: "classic"
}];

for (i = 0; i < productList.length; i++) { 
    productList.appendChild(foodOption);
}
```

Comment: That `textContent` array is **very** odd. It's an array of objects, where each object has exactly one property, and the properties all have different names. If you can change it, I'd suggest changing it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do with jquery,

```
$.each(foodOption.textContent, function (i, value) {
    $('#selectFood').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value',value));
});
```

Comment: he ask for a solution in java-script. but this jQuery look  awesome

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an option element.

```
for (i = 0; i < foodOption.textContent.length; i++) {
   var newElement = document.createElement('option');
   newElement.innerHTML = foodOption.textContent[i];
   productList.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

Comment: I did my option element is `foodOption`

Comment: @Matt you append all object what you have created foodOption is a variable in javascript to turn it into html you first nee to create a html option element. Then that element you need to append it. in your code you try to append an array for each time the for is running. Do you understand the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an array of string rather than array of objects

try this

```
 foodOption.textContent = ["Meat Lovers" , "Buffalo Wings" , "margherita", "classic" ]


$.each(foodOption.textContent, function (index, value) {

    $('#selectFood').append($('<option/>', { value: value, text: value }));

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below code for your solution.

```
var productList = document.getElementById("selectFood");
var textContent = [{ 
    option1: "Meat Lovers"
}, {
    option2: "Buffalo Wings"
}, {
    option3: "margherita"
}, {
    option4: "classic"
}];

for(var iIntex in textContent) {
    var foodOption = document.createElement("option");
    var option=textContent[iIndex]["option"+(iIndex+1)];
    foodOption.setAttribute("value",option);
    foodOption.innerHTML=option;
    productList.appendChild(foodOption);
}
```